# Why does my C/C++ header parser not work?

Tags: c++, c, parsing, boost, header-files

I want to bundle up the [Boost Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) library (and eventually others) into a single amalgamated header so I threw together a small utility program to achieve this goal... only it's not working! I'm unable to determine whether it's a bug or implementation problem (or both) in my program that's causing it to not work correctly.

The program is supposed to open the `boost\preprocessor\library.hpp` header (which includes the entire library) and recursively output to `stdout` all the headers the library needs. Windows Explorer reports there are (as of Boost Preprocessor v1.59.0) 270 header files in the directory tree, but my program is only parsing 204.

I test the amalgamated header by using it in another project that uses Boost Preprocessor. When using the `boost\preprocessor\library.hpp` header the project compiles and works fine, but when using my amalgamated version compilation fails due to not finding all the Boost Preprocessor macros needed.

The full, compilable, code: (Only tested with MSVC v19)

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

// Remember what header files have already been parsed.
std::unordered_map<std::string, bool> have_parsed;

char include_dir[FILENAME_MAX]; // Passed in from the command line.

// Advance given pointer to next non-whitespace character and return it.
char* find_next_nonwhitespace_char(char* start) {
    while(isspace((int)(*start)) != 0) start++;
    return start;
}

#define DIE(condition, str) if(condition) {perror(str); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}

int headers_parsed = 0;

void parse_header(const char* filename) {
    headers_parsed++;
    char path[FILENAME_MAX];
    strcpy(path, include_dir);
    strcat(path, filename);

    // Open file, get size and slurp it up.
    FILE* file = fopen(path, "rb");
    DIE(file == NULL, "fopen()");
    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);
    long int file_size = ftell(file);
    rewind(file);
    char* file_buffer = (char*)malloc(file_size+1); // +1 for extra '\0'
    DIE(file_buffer == NULL, "malloc()");
    size_t got = fread(file_buffer, 1, file_size, file);
    DIE(got != file_size, "fread()");
    fclose(file);

    char* read_index = file_buffer;
    char* end_of_file = file_buffer + file_size;
    *end_of_file = '\0';

    // File is now in memory, parse each line.
    while(read_index < end_of_file) {
        char* start_of_line = read_index;
        // Scan forward looking for newline or 'EOF'
        char* end_of_line = strchr(start_of_line, '\n');
        if(end_of_line == NULL) end_of_line = end_of_file;
        *end_of_line = '\0';
        // Advance to the start of the next line for the next read.
        read_index += (end_of_line - start_of_line) + 1;
        // Look for #include directive at the start of the line.
        char* first_char = find_next_nonwhitespace_char(start_of_line);
        if(*first_char == '#') {
            // This could be an include line...
            char* next_char = find_next_nonwhitespace_char(first_char + 1);
            const char include[] = "include ";
            if(strncmp(next_char, include, strlen(include)) == 0) {
                char* open_brace = find_next_nonwhitespace_char(next_char + strlen(include));
                if(*open_brace++ == '<') {
                    char* close_brace = strchr(open_brace, '>');
                    assert(close_brace != NULL);
                    *close_brace = '\0';
                    if(have_parsed[open_brace] == false) {
                        have_parsed[open_brace] = true;
                        parse_header(open_brace); // Recurse
                    }
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", start_of_line);
    }
    free(file_buffer);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if(argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s {include directory} {first header}\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Ensure the include directory has trailing slash
    strcpy(include_dir, argv[1]);
    size_t len = strlen(argv[1]);
    if(include_dir[len-1] != '\\') {
        include_dir[len] = '\\';
        include_dir[len+1] = '\0';
    }

    parse_header(argv[2]);

    fprintf(stderr, "headers parsed: %d\n", headers_parsed);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Running the compiled program: (Boost is installed in g:\dev)

```
g:\dev\amalgamate\amalgamate.exe g:\dev\ boost\preprocessor\library.hpp > boost_pp.h
headers parsed: 204
```

And the generated `boost_pp.h` header: https://copy.com/vL6xdtScLogqnv9z

What's wrong? **Why is my program not creating a working, amalgamated header?**

Comment: Why are you doing this? Educational purposes?

Comment: Ok, so which files are missing? Do they have anything in common? And what have you observed while debugging the program?

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves Simplicity. IMO, a library should be a single file I can drop into my source directory, include it, and it works. Anything else is unnecessarily complex and time wasting. I've come to like and rely on Boost Preprocessor but, as simple as it is to use now, it could be even simpler.

Comment: You could try to see the output of the preprocessor: (with gnu C, it is g++ -E, with MSVC I think it is something like CL /E), it nearly produces what you want (you will need to strip-off the content of system includes, like <stdlib.h>)

Comment: A wild guess, but could it be that some boost header actually do `#include<...>` (hence no space between the "include" and the "<") or does `#include ".."` instead?

Comment: @Christian.K I don't think that's the problem as any line that isn't recognized as an '#include` directive is (supposed to be) output to stdout, and the word 'include' doesn't appear anywhere in the output.

Comment: It does not appear to be a problem with the Boost headers, but (in case someone else wants to use this code): should you not at least parse the Include Guards `#define` lines? (Which, in turn, requires you to at least *count* – not fully parse – `#ifdef` and `#ifndef`, and then `#else`, `#elif` and `#endif` so you nest them correctly.)

Comment: Header paths are stored in a set (a `map<string, bool>` here basically works like a `set<string>`), so checking include guards isn't necessary - at least as long as all include paths have the same relative directory. By the way, this program would probably greatly benefit from using regexes instead of manually parsing the source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of the headers in the tree aren't actually included by `library.hpp` either because:

- they wrap other headers as an external interface (or because they are deprecated), for example `preprocessor/comma.hpp` simply includes `preprocessor/punctuation/comma.hpp`,
- are to be included via a macro, for example:

  ```
  # define BOOST_PP_ITERATE() BOOST_PP_CAT(BOOST_PP_ITERATE_, BOOST_PP_INC(BOOST_PP_ITERATION_DEPTH()))
  #
  # define BOOST_PP_ITERATE_1 <boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp>
  # define BOOST_PP_ITERATE_2 <boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward2.hpp>
  # define BOOST_PP_ITERATE_3 <boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward3.hpp>
  # define BOOST_PP_ITERATE_4 <boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward4.hpp>
  # define BOOST_PP_ITERATE_5 <boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward5.hpp>
  ```

Which can be used with:

```
#define BOOST_PP_ITERATION_PARAMS_1 (...)
#include BOOST_PP_ITERATE()
```